# Integer in Jenkins when condition

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Can I use an integer for comparison in when condition in Jenkins declarative pipeline ?

I am getting the RC of a previous shell script and then checking it’s RC to run a dependent script. I am doing the if-else check inside a script tag. Can this be done via when or it only takes strings ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `when` directive can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when). Example `when` usage can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when-example).

Note that the `when` directive can be used to conditionally execute a stage, but `when` *cannot* be used to conditionally execute a particular *step* in a stage. To do that, you need to use some other branching structure.

Here is an example of how to use `when` to conditionally execute a stage based on the return code of an [`sh` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) in a previous stage:

```
stage('Stage A - runs before Stage B') {
    steps {
        return_code = sh 'some command', returnStatus: true
    }
}
stage ('Stage B - runs after Stage A') {
    when {
        expression { return return_code == some_value }
    }
    // Rest of stage's definition here
}
```

The `expression` built-in `when` condition is the most powerful `when` condition, since you can construct any arbitrary logical Groovy expression.

There is also the `equals` `when` condition, which in your case you could use like this:

```
when { equals expected: some_value, actual: return_code }
```

If have never personally used the `equals` condition, but I assume it will give a clearer description in your build log explaining why a stage was skipped.